# Is there any way to replace publish a custom data through intel webrtc android sdk, instead of camera data?

Tags: android, webrtc, android-camera, intel, surfaceview

I have the intel webrtc p2p sample app running fine, with publishing camera data.
now I have to replace the camera data with custom data. (data fetched from a surface view as a byte array).
I am trying to find the code part from where intel sends the data and then to replace it.
I couldn't find the code.